# Google Drive Api intergration with php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I want to show my google drive into website.  Which means  if anybody use my website can see google drive files and folder without login.  Here is some code which i am trying to implement.

```
include_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';
    $scopes = array( 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly');

    /**
     * Create AssertionCredentails object for use with Google_Client
     */
    $creds = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $serviceAccountName,
        $scopes,
        file_get_contents($keyFile)
    );

    $creds->sub = $delegatedAdmin;

    /**
     * Create Google_Client for making API calls with
     */
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName($appName);
    $client->setClientId($clientId);
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($creds);

    /**
     * Get an instance of the Directory object for making Directory API related calls
     */
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    $optParams = array(
      'pageSize' => 10,
      'fields' => "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
    );
    $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
    print_r($results); exit;
    /**
```

Can anybody tel me how to achieve this.  I am getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "unauthorized_client", "error_description" : "Unauthorized client or scope in request." }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

```
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}
```

after

```
$client->setAssertionCredentials($creds);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "unauthorized_client", "error_description" : "Unauthorized client or scope in request." }''

Comment: Try to remove `$creds->sub = $delegatedAdmin;`

Comment: Codes seems run, but not able to find list of files . and why this works after removing DeletgateAdmin?

Comment: Take the service account email address and give it access to a directory on your Google drive.

Comment: i didn't undertand this.. can u pls explain

Comment: Visit [this page](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) Share with specific people and share your files with service account

Comment: if we intergate api then why we need to share with other peoples. i want everyone using my website can see my google drive

Comment: Your service account does not have access to your files if you do not give it.

Comment: Thanks  a lot .. i got it

Comment: Can u tell me if i want to access particlar folder how to do that

Comment: Select folder and click share                                                                  ![Image](https://dt.azadicdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/create-shared-folders-in-Google-Drive.png?9423).